# How to set RectangleGeometry as container size in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have an  element containing a RectangleGeometry.
this is in a UserControl later used in a MainWindow.
What i want is the RectangleGeometry to be set as MainWindow size ( or it's container)
How do i do that?

I Am using C#

Comment: Could you expand a little?  Should the Window autosize to its contents?

Comment: I am following some source code. which implements a page flip effect. now it uses a Sheet usercontrol which defines the image size ( dunno how exactly) through a Rectangle. now it's gemoatry is set to a specific value. ( the source code has the images centered on the screen) i want the images to fill entire screen. if i change the  rectangleGeomatry and make it bigger, the image is bigger. however, i want it to strech by window size, as to handle different screen resolution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, dosen't really solve the problem, but as the container size was full size and the window is full size, i just checked the screen  resolution and change the rect accordingly.